# /AppDelegate.h:1:9 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-upgrade

Update react native version from 0.67.2 to .0.71.0 and getting this error

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

# platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
platform :ios, '12.4'
prepare_react_native_project!
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled
# flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(['Debug'],{'Flipper'=>'0.164.0'})
linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end


$FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.6.0' # for Firebase
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

target 'Pstat' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => false,
    :fabric_enabled => false,
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'
  pod 'react-native-html-to-pdf', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-html-to-pdf'
  # pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'FirebaseSessions', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'FirebaseABTesting', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'FirebaseInstallations', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'GoogleDataTransport', :modular_headers => true
  # pod 'nanopb', :modular_headers => true


  target 'Pstat' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
  # use_native_modules!
  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  
  # use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3','Flipper' => '0.87.0','Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
end
```

tried multiple solutions deleted node_modelues, clean project,deleted derived folder but nothing worked for me so what else i can do to resolve it?

As my steps to resolve this
node_modules delete
pods deintegrate
derived folder delete
checked header files

but nothing is working so i am not getting where i am making a mistake